# Cannot reproduce what I have learned or memorised

Tags: academic-life

I am an Accountancy senior level student. My issue is due to lots of information in the books I tend to forget about every specific topic and heading even if I compile notes and memory aids. Reason being that in these professional studies anything can be asked in exams from anywhere. So how do I remember small details at this stage?

Comment: For memorisation, have a look into spaced repetition software (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition). I recommend the Anki flashcard program.

Answer (score 5):

Your question reminds me of the old joke "How do I get to Carnegie Hall?" To which the response is the same, "Practice, man, practice."

You will be expected to know this stuff when you graduate. When studying any subject, there will be a wide variety of rules and formulae you must learn. Normally, when a teacher is trying to get the students to learn them, the students are given exercises to practice them, or scenarios to apply them.

Learning best works in groups, so if you can find someone with whom to study that should help. You can practice with each other reading your answers to see if you understood correctly.

If you do not have an exercises or scenarios to use, ask your teacher. But in the end, **it is all about practice**.

Answer (score 3):

Best advice I have ever gotten from my adviser: don't consider reading as work. You can convince yourself that you've learned a lot from reading. However, if you can't close the book and re-write what you just read from memory, you didn't learn it. So only count what you do, not what you read.

So go do it. I don't know how you'd just go practice accounting, maybe get an internship? Yes, it will be hard at first, but after banging your head against a wall and re-reading your books, you'll find out how to do it. And once you do it for real, you'll never forget how to do it.

A really similar case is learning to program. People ask me which books I read to learn all the programming languages I use and all sorts of questions like that, then they "study up" on the language to remember all of its features, and months later are trying to tackle the problem. I did this at first, but I never really learned how to code until I started freelance web development. When I had a markup due the next day, I was like "how do I do _______ in Javascript?". Google and Stack Exchange helped a lot. I found ways to do things. Now my own code is my source of knowledge on how to do things. All (okay, most) of the time I sat there reading the Javascript book was a waste of time.

In total, I think the biggest thing to get over is the anxiety that you don't know how to do it. You learned enough of it to figure it out / remember it as you need it. That's all you need. Start doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Read and take notes -- but don't overdo this.

You must solve many problems that force you to apply the theorems and principles of Accountancy that you have read.  Also, solving many problems quickly exposes you to what you weren't actually able to commit to memory, so this is a very efficient way of building good memory -- considerably better than reading "lots of information in the books" over and over again.